# Blueimp upload only triggers when second file selected

Tags: jquery, ajax, blueimp

I had the Blueimp jQuery Multiple File Upload plugin working on an internal project without any problems, but then I needed to have it trigger on elements added via AJAX. This code is supposed to upload one or more files, store the filenames to a database (handled by an AJAX request to `includes/file.inc.php`) and then report on the file upload status.

### HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="co_id" value="<?php echo $_POST['co_id']; ?>" id="upload_co_id" />
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

### jQuery

```
$i = 0;
$(document).on('change','#fileupload',function(){
    var url = 'handler.php';
    var co_id = $('#upload_co_id').val();
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<span class="uploaded" id="file'+$i+'" />').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'includes/file.inc.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'co_id': co_id,'file_name': file.name},
                    success: function(data) {
                      if (data == 1) {
                        $('#file'+index).addClass('success');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('#file'+index).removeClass('success');
                        }, 1500);
                      } else {
                        $('#file'+index).addClass('failure');
                        $('#file'+index).append("\n"+data);
                      }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#file'+index).addClass('failure');
                    }
                });
                $i++;
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

This does work, but only the **second** time a file(s) is selected. I know the `$(document).on('change','#fileupload',function(){` gets triggered the first time a file is selected, but it doesn't process the file until I click the file input and select a *different* file(s). I am not getting any console errors.

I have looked into the Blueimp documentation about this, and it talks about using the `add` callback option, but this didn't work at all.

I have been scratching my head over this one for a couple of hours. Why does the `fileupload` plugin only trigger on the second time.

Comment: What exactly are you dynamically adding via AJAX? Ids must be unique within an HTML document, so if you are adding the same input field shown above multiple times(?), that might be the reason.

Comment: @CBroe - no, the element always has a unique ID. It loads the two elements in a layer, but it's only able to show one at a time and removes them from the DOM again after use.